# Vue3 prop String or PropType

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component in a Vue3 project that takes a prop which can either be a string or an object.

So something like this:

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

const Component = defineComponent({
  props: {
    book: {
      type: [String, Object]
    }
  }
})
```

However, if its an object, I want to add a type like so (taken from vue3 docs):

```js
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

interface Book {
  title: string
  year?: number
}

const Component = defineComponent({
  props: {
    book: {
      type: Object as PropType<Book>
    }
  }
})
```

My question is, how can I combine the two like so (this doesn't work, hence my question):

```js
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

interface Book {
  title: string
  year?: number
}

const Component = defineComponent({
  props: {
    book: {
      type: [String, Object as PropType<Book>]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function expression for that prop type:

```js
const Component = defineComponent({
  props: {
    book: {           
      type: [String, () => Object as PropType<Book>]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const isBook = (obj: any): obj is Book => 'title' in obj // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any

    if (isBook(this.book)) {
      console.log(this.book.title)
    }
  }
})
```